# Why does my Processing app take longer to respond over time?

Tags: java, serial-port, processing

I wrote a Processing application that makes a screen invisible when a Serial input is received, and visible again when there is no Serial input. (More specifically, I've attached an RFID reader through Arduino, which sends a signal when it reads a recognised tag)

When I run the app it works quite well. When I remove my tag, the screen goes black and when I replace it, the app goes invisible again. But if I leave the tag on the reader longer, it also takes longer before the screen goes black again when I remove it. But it's not permanent: if the tag is left on longer, the response is slower and vice versa, even after multiple times.

Why is the response time changing? Am I forgetting to close something and thus creating a memory leak? Does the delay somehow increase over time?

This is my code:

```
import processing.serial.*;
Serial myPort;  // Create object from Serial class
String val;     // Data received from the serial port

void setup() {
 String portName = Serial.list()[3]; //change the 0 to a\ 1 or 2 etc. to match your port
  myPort = new Serial(this, portName, 9600); 

  fullScreen();
  surface.setAlwaysOnTop(true); 
  background(000); 
}

void draw() {

  if ( myPort.available() > 0) 
  {  // If data is available,
  val = myPort.readStringUntil('\n');         // read it and store it in val
  } else {
    val=null;}

if (val != null && val.length() > 1) {  //if a serial input is received
 surface.setVisible(false); // make the screen invisible
 }
 else { //otherwise
  surface.setVisible(true); // make the screen visible
}

 delay(50); // wait for 50 ms to stop flickering
}
```

Comment: Why do you have a call to `delay()` inside your `draw()` function? What happens if you remove it?

Comment: That's mostly because the RFID reader isn't great and will occasionally output ```null``` even if there is a tag to be read. If I remove it, the Processing screen turns black every time that happens, which is several times per second.

Comment: After removing the call to `delay()`, do you still have the problem with response time? The random `null` value is a separate problem that we can deal with.

Comment: removing the ```delay()``` does solve the response time problem, but now the screen blinks rapidly whenever serial input is being received. I could try to find a way around that but I'd be interested to find out why the delay would become longer over time when it has a set duration.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert when it comes to the Serial library, so this is mostly a guess, but here goes...

As long as you have the card held up to the reader, you're getting a constant feed of data from it. This goes into a **buffer** which will fill up until you call the `readStringUntil()` function.

Normally this is fine, since you're calling the `readStringUntil()` function 60 times per second, so the buffer doesn't have an opportunity to fill up.

However, since you call the `delay()` function, you're slowing down the rate at which you take data off the buffer. This is causing the buffer to fill up, which means it takes longer to read the data in.

In other words, think of the buffer as a bucket with an opening at the top and a spigot at the bottom. As long as you're holding the card up to the reader, you're filling the bucket from the top. Calling the `readStringUntil()` function is letting a little bit out of the spigot. As long as you keep letting a little bit out, you'll stay caught up with what you're putting in the top of the bucket. But if you slow down the rate at which you open the spigot, you'll be filling the bucket up faster than you can let it out. On the other hand, if you keep opening the spigot faster than you're adding stuff to the top, you're going to have times when nothing comes out.

To fix this problem, you're going to have to more fully understand exactly what your reader is sending over the serial connection. What does a typical line contain? How often are messages sent? Is the same data just repeated over and over again, or does it change over time?

Based on the answer to those questions, you're going to have to rewrite your code to more accurately check whether the card is currently held up to the reader.